# How to redesign and improve this filter?

Tags: filter

Can you please help me to improve this filtering solution? Please share any ideas you have! What would you change?
[image: Current filters]

Comment: Hi RedNaxel and welcome to the site! We're here to discuss UX and design topics of general interest, as described here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Site reviews are not included in this list :-(   Think about your users (when and why do they filter, which criteria are used often, etc. - best to observe them!) and with this information, restructure the page to make the user's tasks easy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do site reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image][image]In general

1. Get rid of fields which have had very low usage in the past.
2. Group items in single list if possible to reduce the number of filters visible.
3. For those which have listed items defined, use select dropdowns. Use dropdowns as much as possible to improve data quality and reduce duplicacies.
4. Display all options in a list if possible and allow multiple selection with checkboxes.
5. Clearing selections is as important as adding filters.

Comment: Do you have suggestions of also what can be done in constraints of improving this without massive architecture refactoring? Thank you!

Comment: 'Equals' or 'Start with' or 'Contains' - options like these are used when the front end is directly fetching from the database. But things can be coded smartly to put priority on these options when passing a value to the back. For example, always show Equals before Starts With and then display Contains at the end.

Another reason I have come across for using these options is, of course, when users demand very fine adjustments. However, that is the case for a few filters not all. Displaying them unnecessarily would be extra effort from all points of view - design, development and use.

Comment: I added an image above suggesting a few visual changes. I see nothing wrong in the patterns used from usability point of view.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ren! Question I am thinking about: can we drop the criteria completely? One of the criteria is 'excluding', so I am thinking if we need to keep the ability to exlude things somehow for the users.

Comment: If you want to have exclusion from the list, the dropdown list needs to have checkboxes for each option. With an additional option called 'All'. Check the Technology filter on this page https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/how-much-electricity-generated-renewable-energy-sources?gallery=votd

Comment: But you see, here user can also exclude text-based values

Comment: Added another image to the top. I'd personally go with that unless there is a constraint regarding vertical screen estate. We can also put the Conditional field at the front before the label.

Comment: Then again, as mentioned earlier, there is nothing wrong with the existing pattern that you have. If the intermediate conditional field is not required just remove it. Vertical or horizontal will depend on whether the filter pane is a sidebar or an overlay.

Comment: Thanks, Ren, that's pretty nice!